Benefits of ROS2 Control
non-technical question here. I am considering using ROS2 control, particularly the differential drive controller, for a project and was curious, what are the benefits of using ROS2 control over writing a controller from scratch? Is it easy to interface with and modify the ROS2 controllers in this library? Any information would be appreciated!

Have a look at tutorials like this one here.
Some advantages of ros2_control

Focus on real-time capability
A set of thoroughly tested controllers in ros2_controllers package
Simulation integration in gazebo classic and gazebo.
Lifecylce management of hardware components and controllers
Command line tools
and more.


Is it easy to interface with and modify the ROS2 controllers in this library?

For sure, the learning curve is steeper, but you will have a more powerful set of tools.

I just found a recap on reddit explaining things quite well.
